# My APP.xaml doesn't see my Locator declaration any more, is it worth to troubleshoot or recreate solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I have this issue that I've been spending too much time on.

Working on Visual Studio 2012, on a Windows Phone 8 app, using MVVM Light.

It's a Compile issue that just arose out of the blue.  My XAML files are now invalid - but just the XAML files where I try to refer to my ViewModels (event handlers bound to buttons, etc), and the reason for that originates from my App.xaml, where it doesn't see Locator in my myapp.ViewModel namespace, so Locator is now thus seen as invalid.

I've even restored old files from a previous backup from 2 weeks ago, (after copying current files somewhere of course),  and the problem still exists.  Even just 2 days ago, my app is compiling great.

( btw specifically, when I say Restore, I'm only talking about restoring the subdirectory that contains all of the individual projects, under the Solution directory )

I've tried doing a Git diff, but I only commit xaml's, and cs files, so it didn't show any of my own errors that would cause this.

This seems like some problem with corruption, possibly in a V.S. binary file that I can't see, and I see myself spinning wheels, and not knowing what code to paste her in stackoverflow.

At what point do you just say :  "Let's just create a brand new solution " ?

I'd hate to do that, and then the  same thing happens again though next week.
However, I'm moving toward a philosophy which says: "dude, get used to doing a re-do, since this stuff happens".  (I'm going to just write a Checklist for how to create a solution from new, with all the packages I need, so it's not such a bummer to start fresh.)

Comment: What is the exact compilation error? Have you tried opening the files in Blend (it sometimes gives slightly better errors)

Comment: I'm actually rebuilding the solution. But there were a variety of them, all relating to the inability of the files to see my various objects that exist in my app.viewmodel namespace. Thanks anyway

Comment: Random question, if I put my Windows Phone 8 project on hold for 6 months because I really need to work on my job skills (javascript, php, etc) ... 

Do you think the Windows phones will be updated to a version of WP that will no longer be compatible with WP8 apps, and only 8.1 and above ?

Comment: This is weird, I pulled open the original non-compiling Solution, the one with the xaml issues, and saw something new, "RaisePropertyChanging not found in current context", so I just commented those out in each of my models (inheriting ViewModelBase).  and now there are no issues... the original solution is now working. Weird

Comment: It would be very surprising indeed if phones stopped supporting 8.0 projects in six months. WP still supports original 7.0 apps onwards.